# Calculations based on sections and other forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to make calculations based on entries made in different sections of the same form. It seems that I can see calculations fields only if they are in the same section, or one big sectional form. This prevents me from using page breaks for a cleaner look and feel.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can now write calculations within sections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) that reference other sections or the parent form.

Simply type `Form.` within calculations to access fields and sections at the form level while writing calculations inside a section.  Also, when writing calculations inside a section which is inside a repeating section, you can use `ParentSection.` to access the parent repeating section item.

Please check out our help documentation for more information:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations#cross-section-calculations

Answer (score -1):

Currently, [calculations in Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/calculations) can access adjacent fields and fields in child sections.  We are actively working on supporting calculations that can access adjacent sections or the parent form.  You can follow our process for this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/dKhdGujx).